# How to use attributeOverride properly to disable 'unique' requirement for username and/or password in FOSUserBundle (yaml doctrine configuration)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using FOSUserBundle in a Symfony2 project, and I want to disable the 'unique' attributes on both username and email fields of the User entity. Maybe that sounds strange at first, but I'm using another combination of fields to make sure that there are unique (active) users in my database, which works fine.

Right now I've setup my User.orm.yml as follows:

```
MyProjectBundle\Entity\User:
    type:  entity
    attributeOverride:
        usernameCanonical:
            unique: false
        emailCanonical:
            unique: false
    table: fos_user
    id:
        id:
            type: guid
            generator:
                strategy: UUID
    fields:
    etc... etc...
```

When I use this setup, and create/update my database via the console, the UNIQUE indexes are removed from the database, just as I wanted. YAY!

However, when I try to generate my project entities with

`doctrine:generate:entities MyProjectBundle`

I get the following error:

`Invalid field override named 'usernameCanonical' for class 'MyProjectBundle\Entity\User'.`

So it is not generating my entities correctly....

For now, I temporarily remove the attributeOverride part in my `User.orm.yml` whenever I want generate the entities, and put them back again if I wish to update my database.

My project is working fine with this workaround, but I would feel much more comfortable knowing why my `attributeOverride` is invalid, and set it up correctly...

Anyone with expierience or suggestions?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug in the entity generator [#3433](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/3433). It was fixed by [#1098](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1098) and backported to 2.4 by [#1231](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1231). You should update to doctrine/orm >=2.4.8.

(By the way the entity generator is for generating entities for the first time and you are supposed to manually edit generated entities after that.)

Comment: Thanks! I'm already on doctrine/orm 2.4.8, but it's good to know that the syntax should be fine....

About generating entities with the `doctrine:generate:entities` command: I'm using it all the time to update my entities, and according to the Symfony docs it's fine to (and i quote:) "run it over and over again", as it only generates new getters and setters... It's just a tool that's too convenient not to use! ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, even after updating doctrine/orm to 2.5.4, this error still occurs...

Comment: That's interesting. Than I think you should create a bug report with a minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue or with a failing test case.